# ar.ols() or arima() for modeling time series

Tags: r, time-series, maximum-likelihood, least-squares

When trying to fit a AR(p) model to a time series in R, it seems that both `ar.ols()` and `arima()` will work. Is there some consideration of when to use which then?

`ar.ols()` seems to use least square estimation, while `arima()` uses maximum likelihood or minimize conditional sum-of-squares (default method).

Is minimizing conditional sum-of-squares equivalent to conditional MLE for Gaussian stationary process? So is `arima()` essentially MLE or conditional MLE?